# Passing variable from DOMPDF controller to view

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I want create a DOMPDF with laravel, and I must passing my variable to view. I've been try passing variable like below, but it still not working yet.

here my Laravel Controller

```
 public function pdf(Request $request, $id){
    $salesorder = $this->show($id)->salesorder;
    $detailservice = $this->show($id)->detailservice;
    $detailemployee = $this->show($id)->detailemployee;

    $data = [$salesorder, $detailemployee, $detailservice];

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('summary.invoice', $data);
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

the error on my view is :

> Undefined variable: salesorder

How to passing some variable from Laravel controller to DOMPDF ?

PS : `dd($data)` result is correctly

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the `data` as below

```
$data = [
    'salesorder'     => $salesorder,
    'detailemployee' => $detailemployee,
    'detailservice'  => $detailservice
];
```

or try using `compact`

```
$data = compact('salesorder', 'detailemployee', 'detailservice');
```

Comment: hi, it's still not working yet. When I'm using `compact` the error is still the same, but when I'm using your first way, the page was take a long time to load.

Comment: @rafitio I removed the `[]` from compact. Edited the answer please try again. Is the other way loading? or its taking long time & not loading also

Comment: @rafitio One thing I can suggest in slowness is, store following `$this->show($id)` code's return in a variable and use that var to assign the other values. This way the function will get execute only one time rather that three times

Comment: yes, the error still same. But now it's has been working, I was manually write my html on my controller.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131890/discussion-between-saumini-navaratnam-and-rafitio).

Answer (score 4):

You may try this following

```
public function pdf(Request $request, $id){
    $salesorder = $this->show($id)->salesorder;
    $detailservice = $this->show($id)->detailservice;
    $detailemployee = $this->show($id)->detailemployee;

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('summary.invoice', array('salesorder' => $salesorder,'detailemployee'=>$detailemployee,'detailservice'=>$detailservice));
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use library function to do that easily.

```
$pdf_text = "It will be the text you want to load";
PDF::loadHTML($pdf_text)->save('public/you-file-name.pdf');
```

You can change the orientation and paper size, and hide or show errors (by default, errors are shown when debug is on)

```
PDF::loadHTML($pdf_text)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->save('public/you-file-name.pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following.

```
$html = view('summary.invoice', ['salesorder' => $salesorder, 'detailemployee' => $detailemployee, 'detailservice' => $detailservice])->render();
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$invPDF = $pdf->loadHTML($html);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this may help others. you need to use array key in your view.

Controller:

```
$data = [
     'foo'    => $bar,
];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
return $pdf->stream('doc.pdf');
```

View:

```
<p>{{$foo}}</p>
```

Comment: This is not working. I tried and I created an array like that but I am getting an error saying "Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given"